# Error while trying to render a vid file from firebase using mongoDB and ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I am trying to make something similar to youtube clone app using Node, express, mongoose and ejs. When trying to use res.render() to send results to the iframe in the ejs file, im getting an error.

Here is the code for both the ejs and server files:-

index.js:-

```
>! 
>! `const express = require('express');
>! const mongoose = require('mongoose');
>! const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
>! const ejs = require('ejs');
>! 
>! const app = express();
>! 
>! app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
>! extended: true
>! }));
>! app.use(express.static("public"));
>! app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
>! 
>! mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/VidDb");
>! 
>! const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
>! name:{
>! type:String,
>! required:true,
>! unique:true
>!   },
>! email:{
>! type:String,
>! required:true,
>! unique:true
>!   },
>! password:{
>! type:String,
>! required:true,
>!   },
>! image:{
>! type:String,
>!   },
>! },{timestamps:true});
>! 
>! const User = mongoose.model("User",userSchema);
>! 
>! const vidSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
>! vidName:{
>! type:String,
>! required:true,
>! unique:true
>!   },
>! vidThumb:{
>! type:String,
>! required:true,
>! unique:true
>!   },
>! vidLink:{
>! type:String,
>! required:true,
>! unique:true
>!   },
>! likes:{
>! type:Number,
>! default:0
>!   },
>! views:{
>! type:Number,
>! default:0
>!   },
>! });
>! 
>! const Vids = mongoose.model("Vid",vidSchema);
>! 
>! app.get("/",function(req,res){
>! Vids.find().then(function(vids,err){
>! res.render("index",{
>! videos:vids
>!       });
>!   });
>! });
>! 
>! app.get("/vids/:vidId",function(req,res){
>! const videoID = req.params.vidId;
>! Vids.findById(videoID).then(vid => {
>! res.render("vid",{
>! video:vid
>!     });
>!   });
>! });
>! 
>! app.listen(3000,function(){
>! console.log("Server Started");
>! });
>! 
>! `
```

vid.ejs:-

```
`<%- include('partials/header'); -%>
<!-- <video
    id="my-video"
    class="video-js"
    controls
    preload="auto"
    width="640"
    height="264"
    poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg"
    data-setup="{}"
  >
    <source src="<%= video.vidLink %>" type="video/mp4" />
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
      web browser that
      <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank"
        >supports HTML5 video</a
      >
    </p>
  </video> -->



<iframe width="1020" height="815" src= "<%= video.vidLink %>" ></iframe>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/8.0.4/video.min.js"></script>
<%- include('partials/footer'); -%>

`
```

I get the link when console logging but when trying to send the link to the ejs file, it doesnt work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the issue that you aren't able to pass the var/link in ejs file. Right?

The issue is you are passing the wrong ejs file path. When you use `res.render()` it tries to find the file path and you just passed the name.

Your code:

```
app.get("/vids/:vidId",function(req,res){
   const videoID = req.params.vidId;
     Vids.findById(videoID).then(vid => {
        res.render("vid",{
          video:vid
        });
    });
});
```

Updated Code:

```
app.get("/vids/:vidId", function (req, res) {
     const videoID = req.params.vidId;
     Vids.findById(videoID).then((vid) => {
        res.render(__dirname+"/vid.ejs", { appUrl:'http://localhost:3000',
          video: vid,
        });
     });
});
```

Here:

- **__dirname**: We use this to define the directory path like in which directory your project is.
- **appUrl**: use for API url. when you push your code into the server and you are passing any file path in ejs file then it will be accessed via appUrl. This is optional.

**NOTE**: When you render any ejs template, remove all the comments. For more information visit [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) page.

I used this ejs:

```
<iframe width="1020" height="815" src= "<%= video.vidLink %>" ></iframe>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/8.0.4/video.min.js"></script>
```

Data:
[image]

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Due to academic I currently stopped working on that project, will definitely try this when I start working on it again.

Comment: If you find this useful, then please upvote.